# How to save multiplication computation time between a dense vector and a not that sparse matrix?

Tags: sparse-matrix, scipy, numpy, dense-matrix

I am trying to compute $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{u}$ for many times in my algorithm, where $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. The problem is that, during the computational process of the algorithm, $\mathbf{X}$ is a constant, however, more and more elements in $\mathbf{X}$ can be changed to zero, which might help us to save computational time. $\mathbf{u}$ is just a variable. This process is kind similar to a process of changing a dense matrix to a band matrix and finally a sparse matrix. But the band matrix is not standard as it might look like a boomerang or something else.
I know that using a sparse matrix to represent the $\mathbf{X}$ can speed up the multiplication, but the advantage only appears when the sparsity is above 90% percent. It is not suitable for me because most of the time my $\mathbf{X}$ is not that sparse, and even when it reached 90% percent sparsity, the speed-up ratio of the Sparse Matrix multiplication in Scipy is not that oblivious. 
I use NumPy in python to apply the multiplication $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{u}$, which is really fast. I wonder whether it is possible to be faster as we are sure that more and more elements in $K$ are zeros and unimportant. Can we speed up it by using space to exchange for computational time?

Comment: How big is your matrix? If it's smallish then sparsity just isn't going to be able to help you much.

Comment: As it is an algorithm, we hope it would be able to deal with large-scale problems. The matrix would have hundreds of dimensions in some real applications.

Comment: Do you mean the order of the matrix is at most a few hundred? If so that's not very big at all for a matrix vector multiply, and simply using BLAS will probably not be a bad solution

Comment: Before you go down this rabbit hole, you should check whether your algorithm is spending a lot of time on the $Xu$ multiplcations.  It could well be that there are other more important hot spots.

Comment: What do you mean by "X is a constant, however more and more elements in X can be changed to zero"?

Comment: What's the order in which you get each $u$? For example, do you get $u_k$, compute $Xu_k$, and then use this to compute $u_{k + 1}$? Or do you get a big batch of $u$s at once? If it's the latter case, you can speed things up a lot by stacking those vectors into a dense matrix $U$ and computing $XU$ instead.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm only needs to compute something like $\mathbf{u_k}= \mathbf{v}/\mathbf{X}\mathbf{u_{k-1}}$, the multiplication is almost the whole computational burden. However, the elements in $\mathbf{X}$ will gradually change, more and more elements would be equal to 0 during the algorithm. sorry for my type error cause I am in the hospital with a mobile phone.